# When is an Id annotated with @GeneratedValue set?

Tags: java, jpa

When can I reliably know that the `id` field annotated with `@GeneratedValue` of a newly created entity has been set by the `persistence provider`?

The JPA specification is not very specific about this. I've seen similar questions but they get different and confusing answers. I know that once the transaction is committed, the id has been set, but what about if the transaction is still running and I need the id?

How can I reliably get it?

Comment: because "it depends" on the generation strategy ... care to share which one you mean?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this. calling [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--)() method may push the unsaved data to database.

```
// Use persist in a transaction
// It doesn't guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately,
// the assignment might happen at flush time so call the flush method.
public T persist(T obj) {
    entityManager.persist(obj);
    entityManager.flush();
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Is the `flush` method guaranteed to cause synchronization of the persistence context to the database? Isn't it just a hint to the `persistence provider`?

Comment: I've had it work for me, too. I just didn't know if it was by chance or a requirement guaranteed by `JPA` specification.

Comment: I have observed the HibernateImpl for JPA, See the DefaultFlushEventListener class. It states, Defines the default flush event listeners used by hibernate for flushing session state in response to generated flush events.